# How to analyze multiple query parameters in Google Analytics

Tags: google-analytics, google-tag-manager

I'm setting up Google Analytics for a website where a user can find an event to attend (concerts, plays, etc.). The results can be filtered by 5 different parameters.

So, unfiltered results would look like: example.com/event-finder/

And filtered results showing concerts in January or February would look like: example.com/event-finder?type=concert&month=jan,feb

I'm struggling to figure out the best way to use the query parameters in Google Analytics to analyze filtering behavior.

Example questions I'd want to be able to pull answers for:

- What percentage of results were filtered by type?
- What percentage of results were also sorted by month?
- What is the most common type filtered by?

I have full access to both Google Analytics and Tag Manager but I suspect I shouldn't do this with events or custom dimensions and that there's got to be a way to use the query parameters to do this in a clean way.

I've tried to use a new view and site search to group the types of filters. Seems like it could work, but seems hacky and limited.

I've considered pushing those values into custom dimensions, but that too seems like overkill.

I've considered pulling content reports into Google Sheets and sorting through things there, but I'm 1) not entirely sure how I'd do that and 2) suspect there may be an easier approach.

Let me know if you have any questions or need more clarification. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried to use "category parameters" when configuring site search (admin -> view settings)? You could set the "type" as a category parameter. You can also enter multiple parameters in there.

Check this [screenshot of site search configuration](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6OOq2.png)